# Getting an output for each new measurment from Keithley 2400

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project where I am using a Keithley 2400 Sourcemeter to measure surface conductivity of a specific material. I have a fixed delay number (say 1000 ms) between each measurement (I am using LabTracer 2.0). For the purpose of my project I have to measure the conductivity on three different points on the surface of the specimen. In order to achieve that I am using an Arduino microcontroller which controls the circuit’s endings – three resistors on different places on the surface of the material. The Arduino board starts the process when it is being triggered by the Keithley (when the current flow starts – utilizing analogRead() )
My problem is that the delay time of Keithley is not exactly 1000 ms, and this causes out of sync phenomena.
An ideal solution to this would be if I could get an output in real-time each time a new measurement is taken by the Keithley. In that way I could use this output as a reference to whether open or close the circuit. The analogRead command is useful for the start of the circuit, as it gives an output when the current flow starts. Ideally I would like to receive another output for each new measurement.

The way I am thinking the whole process is this:

Initialization of the circuit by setting resistor_1 to OPEN

Start Keithley

Take measurement

CLOSE resistor_1

OPEN resistor_2

If new measurement is taken then:

CLOSE resistor_2

OPEN resistor_3

If new measurement is taken then:
CLOSE resistor_3

OPEN resistor_1

etc…

Any suggestions on that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know if I got your idea well but... have you considered using interrupts? So, your `if new measurement is taken` becomes the interrupt trigger, and the Arduino starts reading the `analogRead()`. I hope this can be somewhat useful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved the problem by switching sequentially between two different delays for the arduino.